# Only show a span with php if

Tags: php, if-statement, attributes, label

I would like to add a (see the span) link next to the attribute size ( like here: https://www.keurigkindje.nl/product/test-trui/)

As you can see that link is now also placed net to the aatribute color. In the code I would like to make it only been shown next to the attribute size.

Something like php if (...

```
<label for="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?>
```

```
<span style="font-size:12px; font-weight:300; margin-left:12px; text-decoration:underline;" class="maattabel5" style="cursor: pointer;">welke maat past?</span>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or what problem you're describing.  What specifically doesn't work in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add condition before span like

```
<?php if($attribute_name == "Kies uw Maat"){ ?>
    <span style="font-size:12px; font-weight:300; margin-left:12px; text-decoration:underline;" class="maattabel5" style="cursor: pointer;">welke maat past?</span>
<?php } ?>
```